# I'm looking for an ember helper function like {{json JSON-flat-definition}} to define an attribute or argument. Where to find and how to use?

Tags: function, templates, ember.js, helper

Built-In Helper Functions in Ember (over Handlebars) are already defined such as a {{let}}, an {{array}}, an {{hash}}, so for me the base of a {{json}} helper, accepting any json string as parameter to define attributes of the template or arguments of the component. Is there such a helper? How does the json-definition-string looks like, as the built-ins only use blanks to structure the data?

https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/helper-functions/#toc_the-let-helper
https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/helper-functions/#toc_the-array-helper
https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/helper-functions/#toc_the-hash-helper

So expected is something like

```
<Greeting @people={{json
    firstName='Tom'
    lastName='Dale'

    firstName='Yehuda'
    lastName='Katz'

    firstName='Jen'
    lastName='Weber'
  }} />
```

Answer (score 3):

There is not. You would need to call `array` and `hash` yourself. So you can do this:

```
@people={{array
  (hash
    firstName='Tom'
    lastName='Dale'
  )
  (hash
    firstName='Yehuda'
    lastName='Katz'
  )
  (hash
    firstName='Jen'
    lastName='Weber'
  )
}}
```

Be careful what you consider "a json string", because you used it for "a recursive data structure composed from arrays and dictionaries" and not actually `JSON`. Because `JSON` is a *serialization format*, or, by its very name "JavaScript Object Notation" a notation. If you have the same data in the same structure but a different format its no longer `JSON`.

So if you do

```
const foo = {
  name: "something"
};
```

this is *not* a *JSON Object*! `foo` will definitly not be an *JSON Object*, it will just be an `Object`. You could argue that the part of the *source code* starting from `{` to `}` is a *JSON Object* but even that is wrong. `JSON` defines a *subset* of the valid Javascript Object Notation and

```
{
  name: "something"
}
```

is *not* valid `JSON` because `name` is not in double quotes.

So if you *would* build a `json` helper it would be used like this:

```
  <MyComponent @data={{json "[{ \"firstName\": \"Tom\" }]"}} />
```

thats in no way nice to use and would basically primarily useful if you have a actual `JSON` value inside a `string` and want to parse it. This helper would also be very easy to write:

```
import { helper } from '@ember/component/helper';

export default helper(function json([json]/*, hash*/) {
  return JSON.parse(json);
});
```

---

One thing to mention here is that there is an [`RFC` proposed](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/621) to introduce a leteral syntax to define arrays and hashes into ember.

So maybe *someday* something like this *could* become part of ember:

```
@people={{[
  (
    firstName='Tom'
    lastName='Dale'
  )
  (
    firstName='Yehuda'
    lastName='Katz'
  )
  (
    firstName='Jen'
    lastName='Weber'
  )
]}}
```

but currently you have to call `array`/`hash` at every level as shown above.